# OpenCv2 ParallerLoop compilation error

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, parallel-processing

I want to rewrote my software to use multiple cores.
Unfortunetally im always getting an errors. I do not know if i need specific includes,
the syntax is wrong, or maybe it is deprecated ?

Full code:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

class Parallel_proc : public ParallelLoopBody
{
    private:
        Mat img;
        Mat retVal;

    public:
        Parallel_proc(Mat pGrayImg)
            : img(pGrayImg){}

        virtual void operator()(const Range& range) const
        {
            for(int i = range.start; i < range.end; i++)
            {
                //code here
            }
        }
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        //cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, cascadesNumber), Parallel_proc(pGrayImg);
}

    return 0;

}
```

G++ error:

```
example.cpp:16:1: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
```

Interesting thing is that g++ is pointing at first character of the line, but clang++ is more specific:

```
example.cpp:15:30: error: expected class name
class Parallel_proc : public ParallelLoopBody
                             ^
```

compilation command:

```
(clan)g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -I. -o example example.cpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Comment: have you tried adding "cv::ParallelLoopBody" instead of "ParallelLoopBody". That class is under namespace "cv".

Comment: i have added my namespaces to original question

Comment: what is 'type' ? also, `Mat& retVal` either has to get initialized or must not be a reference

Comment: Seems that it just does not recognize ParallelLoopBody. Put the whole code, at least minimal complete example showing the compilation error

Comment: You did not forget the ';' at the end of the class did you?

Comment: with proper semicolons at the class ends, and Mat retVal, it compiles here

Comment: i did not missed ; at the end. I will paste full example.

Comment: Did you solve this problem in the end? It occurred in my code right now. It worked before, then I had to format Ubuntu and now it doesn't.